# Get phone number from scanned qr code?

Tags: qr-code

I read you can setup a qrcode to send an sms message when scanned. My question is, if I scan a qrcode with my phone and that qr code sends a sms message, does it send the phone number that scanned it to send that text message so I know what number to text back if need be?

Comment: Looks like when scanning a qrcode meant for sms it only brings up the text messaging screen, you still have to click the send button. Thought it automatically sent the sms message. So it would pass the phone number in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: it's going to depend on the app (and device) the user uses to scan the code.

A qr code is just text. An "sms" qr code just starts with the text "SMSTO:". It's up to the app to decide what to do when it sees that.

What an app can even do depends on the platform. Maybe you can directly send an sms without user intervention on some platforms, but you can't on iOS (unless you don't send the sms from the phone but instead some net service that will send an sms for you; in that case, I strongly suspect you get a different source number).

So unless somehow control what the user is using to scan the code, you don't know what the result will be.

Answer (score 0):

When using qrcodes to send a sms message it only prompts you to the send text message screen on your phone pre-populating it with the message embedded in the qrcode and the number embedded in the qrcode. So it will send the number with the text. They just have to click the send button on their phone.